# Best practice for allowing multiple Vulkan instances as part of 'renderer' objects

Tags: vulkan

I'm writing a library in C to abstract multiple graphics APIs including Vulkan behind the same interface.

Currently, the library allows for the creation of multiple 'renderer' objects, which contain a whole 'state' of a graphics API - as it stands, this translates to having one Vulkan instance per renderer, for example.

However, I am using [volk](https://github.com/zeux/volk) to load Vulkan symbols. This library loads global functions based on the extensions enabled for a Vulkan instance, and problems arise when attempting to create multiple instances, potentially with different layers/extensions enabled.

For example, if I create an instance with debug utils enabled, the associated functions like `vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT` are loaded as expected. If I then create another instance *without* debug utils enabled, these functions seem to be unloaded, which sets their function pointers to NULL, causing a segfault when the instance that enabled them attempts to call them.

At the end of the day, supporting multiple Vulkan instances seems to be introducing a lot of issues - is there perhaps a better way of abstracting this design, or should I just limit the user to creating one Vulkan renderer (and therefore one instance) per program?

Comment: "*multiple 'renderer' objects, which contain a whole 'state' of a graphics API - as it stands, this translates to having one Vulkan instance per renderer, for example.*" What is the purpose of this? It's not clear what a "renderer" in your system is supposed to mean, or why you would need two of them or why two of them would need to use different `VkInstance` objects.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I'm designing a 'renderer' as an object that can represent a Vulkan state, or an OpenGL state (however that would work), or a state of some other API. This is all assuming other APIs like Metal and D3D12 don't use global state like OpenGL (maybe I'm assuming wrong). Essentially, multiple renderers could be used to allow for e.g. OpenGL calls and Vulkan calls in the same application. I just don't know how to allow for multiple renderers for the same API, or if I should at all.

Comment: "*I'm designing a 'renderer' as an object that can represent a Vulkan state, or an OpenGL state (however that would work), or a state of some other API.*" But what does that *entail*? In your head, you have the idea of what things you consider "Vulkan state" and what things you don't. But I don't know what those things are. You say you want it to be a `VkInstance`, but like... why? What are you trying to do that these "renderers" could not share instances? You talk about how OpenGL uses "global state", but the Vulkan equivalent of that is a command buffer, not an instance. Or maybe a device.

Comment: The renderers could probably share a single `VkInstance`, but then surely it wouldn't be possible to create a renderer with different features enabled than another one created earlier, since the shared instance would be immutable?

Comment: What kind of "features" are you talking about? What kinds of thing do you think a `VkInstance` governs? That's really the point of my questions; you talk about everything in terms of generalities like "state" and the like. But *which* "state"? Sit down and make a list of the kinds of stuff you want this "renderer" to encapsulate, and what kind of independence should two distinct "renderers" have.

Comment: Regarding the `VkInstance`, my interpretation is that it is a representation of the Vulkan implementation, since instance-level extensions are related to the OS and implementation rather than the devices. By 'features' I pretty much mean instance-level extensions (apologies that wasn't clear on my part). I would like the renderer to encapsulate a logical device and everything created from it, so queues and command pools/buffers etc. I think I'm right in saying that this can be achieved for these objects?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253940/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-kosude).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function pointers obtained through a particular `VkInstance` object (through `vkGetInstanceProcAddr`) cannot be used with different instance objects. This is just as true of the Vulkan SDK as it is of Volk. That is, a function pointer obtained as the result of calling `volkLoadInstance(some_instance)` can only be used on other `some_instance` objects or those derived from them (like `VkDevice`s).

Note that Volk doesn't hand you function pointers; it initializes global function pointers. Therefore, if you call `volkLoadInstance`, all of the global functions it hands you are bound to that instance. You can call it again for a different instance, but you're just changing which global pointers you're talking about.

That is, Volk is specifically designed to be used with a single instance. It has functionality for easily using it with multiple devices without dynamic dispatch logic (`volkLoadDeviceTable` returns a table of function pointers specific to a device), but it has no similar construct for instances.

As such, trying to allow each "renderer" to have its own `VkInstance` object is going to run into problems. `volkLoadInstance` is not a *fast* function.

The reason Volk is written this way is because creating multiple instances like this is generally... not useful. Vulkan instance extensions tend to be about the interaction between your code and the operating system.

Consider `VK_KHR_surface`. This is an instance extension that acts as glue between your program and an OS window. If you want to render into a window, you need this instance extension. But the glue between the OS window (represented by a `VkSurfaceKHR`) and a Vulkan device is governed by `VK_KHR_swapchain`, which is a *device* extension. A device created from an instance doesn't have to use that extension. If it doesn't, then it won't be able to render into a surface.

But it doesn't harm the device in any way to have been created from an instance that uses `VK_KHR_surface`. So you should get your "renderers" together and set down a list of instance extensions that they could rely on, and then require them for the one `VkInstance` that they all share.

---

Broadly speaking, separate `VkInstance` objects exist primarily for DLLs, where there is a hard barrier between the global state of two pieces of code that happen to exist in the same program. One DLL can use a Vulkan instance, while the main program uses a separate one. The separate instances, and attendant global instance function pointers, make it easy for these two pieces of code to co-exist without stomping on each other.

Comment: So just to clarify; would this involve the user setting the requirements of any renderers they would use *first*, and then calling some function that would actually 'create' those renderers, creating the shared instance, separate device handles, etc?

Comment: @kosude: Who is "the user" in this context? Are we talking about someone using a program or someone using a *library*?

Comment: the person using the library.

Comment: @kosude: Yes, the implementer of a "renderer" would have to express their requirements of the Vulkan interface. Note that many tools that rely on external creation of Vulkan interfaces (like GLFW) already do so.